# How to find Cosmos DB Endpoint and where to get lib directory referenced in this code?

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

[Here is sample code for querying a CosmosDB](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-js/blob/216672a679ab389e5b341280eeacab1cab3691e4/samples/ContainerManagement/app.js#L47-L51)

Here is the part of the code I am concerned with replicating so I can make queries on my own database.

```
const cosmos = require("../../lib/");
const CosmosClient = cosmos.CosmosClient;
const config = require("../Shared/config");
const databaseId = config.names.database;
const containerId = config.names.container;

const endpoint = config.connection.endpoint;
const masterKey = config.connection.authKey;

// Establish a new instance of the CosmosClient to be used throughout this demo
const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint, auth: { masterKey } });
```

I'm not sure what my endpoint should be in order to query the database. My queries are Read-only (doesn't need to be strictly read only, but for what I'm doing, read-only is all that's needed), but I don't know what is in `../../lib/` that the `cosmos` variable is set equal to, and I don't know what the endpoint variable should contain (obviously some sort of endpoint, but which one). The `../../lib/` directory doesn't appear to be in the github repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection information can be found in the `Keys` section of the Azure portal.

The endpoint is the value in the `URI` section.

In case of the CosmosDB emulator, the default `URI` is `https://localhost:8081`.

[image]

Comment: Do you know how I can get the lib directory? Is it a node package I can import?

Comment: @jaredad7 Yeah you get get that from the Node SDK 2.0 from npm here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/cosmos